# Unexpected Warning - mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Tags: php, mysql

I seem to be experiencing an issue whereby the `mysql_fetch_array` function is reporting `Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given` even though the parameter I'm passing is a `resource`.

I understand that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, and that the database interaction should be done using `mysqli` or even better, prepared statements, however I am unable to change the methods used to interact with the database in this instance as it isn't software that I have the authorisation to do this on.

The structure is as follows:

```
$sql; //contains the query
if(!$result = mysql_query($sql)) {
    //report error
} else {
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($instance = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            //runs once, even though there are 3 results.
        }
    } else {
        //no rows
    }
}
```

The warning is issued on the line `while($instance = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {` and indicates I've passed a boolean to the function.

When I do a `var_dump` on `$result` on the line before `while($instance = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {` I receive the output:

```
resource(22) of type (mysql result)
```

When I run the query generated in `$sql` manually, I get 3 results.

I'm struggling to find an explanation as to why I recieve this warning, and the loop only executes once.

Again, I understand that using `mysql_` isn't recommended due to being unsafe & deprecated, and that there are certain things done incorrectly in the code such as accidental assignment (which in this case is obviously intentional) but regardless, the code should still execute correctly.

Comment: Inside the while loop body, are you perhaps changing or overwriting the $result variable?

Comment: `var_dump($result)` after `if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {`

Comment: r u using $result variable inside the while loop? may be its updated inside the while loop check it again

Comment: @SatishSharma (& Tularis) both correct. Like I said in the answer, simple mistake overlooked by myself after looking too far in to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that your `while` loop "runs once, even though there are 3 results", I'm going to take a shot in the dark and say that you are using `$result` in the loop contents by mistake.

Comment: my thoughts exactly :)

Comment: Simple mistake overlooked by myself, looked way to far into it. (Will mark as answer after time restriction)